# How to make a counter in a function?

Tags: counter

I would like to change the value of n from 1 to 10 and it should show me the value of x1 for each n
So, How can I do that something like a counter (n)

```
n = 1; a = 4; 
G = -Exp[-(-a*Log[y/10] + 1 - 
       Sqrt[(a*Log[y/10] - 1)^2 - 2 (1/2 Log[y/10]^2 - a*Log[y/10])])];
x1 = NIntegrate[G, {y, 54.9218, 54.9218 + n*(-9.9/10)}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
G = -Exp[-(-a*Log[y/10] + 1 - 
       Sqrt[(a*Log[y/10] - 1)^2 - 2 (1/2 Log[y/10]^2 - a*Log[y/10])])];

data = ({#, NIntegrate[G, {y, 54.9218, 54.9218 + # (-9.9/10)}]} & /@ 
   Range[10])

(* {{1, 5.38825}, {2, 10.6785}, {3, 15.8707}, {4, 20.965}, {5, 25.9612}, 
  {6, 30.8594}, {7, 35.6596}, {8, 40.3617}, {9, 44.9659}, {10, 49.4721}} *)
```

However the integral can be done exactly

```
int[n_] = With[{a = Rationalize[54.9218]},
   Integrate[G, {y, a, a + (-99 n/100)}]] // Simplify

(* -((99 n (-274609 + 2475 n))/5000000) *)

Plot[int[n], {n, 0, 10},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[data]}]
```

[image]